# Python Flask URI Depth

Tags: python, flask, uri

I was wondering how to throw an exception or error for the case that a URI is 'too long' in the context of my REST API.

For example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/foo/
```

and

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/foo/bar
```

are acceptable within the parameters of my app but the following should not be allowed:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/foo/bar/go
```

and "go" could really be anything, including a long string of gibberish. Currently, the app returns a blank jsonified output when I enter a string in this place.

I'd like to return an error though if a user tries to enter anything beyond that third slash.

The big gotcha here is that the entry "bar" could legitimately have a backslash (e.g. `b / ar`) so I've tried to provision for that too.

To give more context around things, here is a snippet of code that does some special handling:

```
@app.route('/foo/<path:bar>', methods=['GET'])
def list_single_bar(bar):
    for i in [";"]:
        if i in bar:
            bar = bar.replace(i,"")
    for i in [" / ",": "," "," & ","@","#"]:
        if i in bar:
            bar = bar.replace(i,"-")
```

Pretty ugly but I'm basically trying to normalize this part of the URI string so that I can pass it on to build a URL string and get some results from a website.

The URL being built mostly substitutes the dash character in place of spaces.

Comment: Since you're using `<path:bar>` flask is going to match almost anything after `/foo/`.  Have you considered checking the length of `bar` and throwing an exception?  Flask supports custom error handlers as seen here:  http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/apierrors/

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, doing a length check occurred to me but the only thing is that "bar" could theoretically be a pretty long string. And if I set the max length to be say 30 chars, wouldn't I still have the same problem if I enter a shorter string followed by additional directories? The reason I needed path: too was to account for backslashes in the string... sounds like it's a double-edged sword of sorts.

Comment: So perhaps what you should do instead of accepting a conditionally long string in your URI, instead ask the consuming application to POST the path to you in the body.  That way, at least, you aren't battling Flask's router limitations and will have full control of the outcome of the request.

Comment: Ah, so that might look something like a userinput form on the page where you enter the string and that gets parsed and then passed on as a POST request. Rather than opening up the potential of someone tampering or fudging up the URL directly.